# Using complex comparators in tsung script

Tags: tsung

Is it possible to use an `if condition` in tsung and use a `greater than` comparison rather than a straight `equals` and `not equals` comparison?
Or is it possible to use the `and` or `or` operator to combine comparisons?

Comment: 1 - [Loops, If, Foreach](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/user_manual.html#htoc71); 2,3 - not, but [erlang code usage possible for dynamic variable](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/user_manual.html#htoc69).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no greather then operator at this time in tsung, only *equal* and *not equal*. It is not possible to combine comparisons with *and* and *or*.